# calculation user's age on fly, optimization. mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have next (strange) query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM z1 INNER JOIN c c ON (z1.id=c.id) 
INNER JOIN i ON (c.member_id=i.member_id)
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(i.birthyear,"-",i.birthmonth,"-",i.birthday),"%Y%m%d000000") BETWEEN '19820605000000' AND '19930604235959' AND c.id NOT IN (658887)
GROUP BY c.id
```

user's birthday keeps in db in three different colums. but here is the task to find out user's stuff which ages are in specific range.

The worst thing, that mysql will calculate age for each selected record and compare it with condition and it's not good :( is there any way to make it faster ?

this is the plan

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | z1    | index  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL               | 176659 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,member_id | PRIMARY | 4       | z1.id          |      1 |   100.00 |                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY | 4       | c.member_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you want to take advantage of indexes (and you probably do!) apply the formula to the constant ('19820605000000', etc.) rather than to the column!

Comment: @Strawberry could you please clarify what do you mean ?

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the right answer is to fix your schema. i.e. data should be normalized, use native keys wherever practical and use the right data types.

Looking at your post, at least you've provided a EXPLAIN plan - but the table structures would help too.

Why is the table z1 in the query? You don't explicitly filter using it, and you don't use the result anywhere.

Why do you do bot a DISTINCT and a GROUP BY - you're asking the DBMS to do the same work twice.

Why do you use 'c' as an alias for 'c'?

Why are you using NOT IN to exclude a single value?

Why do you compare your date values as strings?

It's posible that the optimizer is getting confused about the best way to resolve the query - but you've not provided any information to support this - what proportion of the data is filterd by the age rule? You may get better results using the birthday / i table to drive the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM c 
INNER JOIN i ON (c.member_id=i.member_id)
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(
       CONCAT(i.birthyear,'-', i.birthmonth,'-',i.birthday)
       ,"%Y-%m-%d")    
BETWEEN 19820605000000 AND 19930604235959 
AND c.id <> 658887
AND i.birthyear BETWEEN 1982 AND 1993
```

Comment: yep without age calculation it works 5 times faster :) @Stephan bellow suggest the way how to deal with age, will think about it. If I could i would remake totally db schema, and of course I woul rewrite query itself, but  I can't :( this is wy I'm looking any (unknown to me) easy and magic way how to make it faster as cheap as possible :) thanks for your questions, at least for one of them i don't have any answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Alter `i` table and add a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column named `date_of_birth` with a `INDEX` on it :

```
ALTER TABLE i ADD date_of_birth DATETIME NOT NULL, ADD INDEX date_of_birth;
UPDATE i SET date_of_birth = CONCAT(i.birthyear,"-",i.birthmonth,"-",i.birthday);
```

And use this query which should be faster:

```
SELECT 
    c.id
FROM 
    i
INNER JOIN c 
    ON c.member_id=i.member_id
WHERE
    i.date_of_bith BETWEEN '1982-06-05 00:00:00' AND '1993-06-04 23:59:59'
    AND c.id NOT IN (658887)
GROUP BY
    c.id
ORDER BY
    NULL
```

Comment: thanks, it might be most efficient way in current situation ;)

Comment: np, also post the explain output for this query to see if indeed it is better

Answer (score 1):

You've asked me to explain what I mean. Unfortunately there are two problems with that.

The first is that I don't think that this can be adequately explained in a simple comments box.

The second is that I don't really know what I'm talking about, but I'll have a go...

Consider the following example - a simple utility table containing dates up to 2038 (when the whole UNIX_TIMESTAMP thing stops working anyway)...

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (
    dt date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`dt`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, the following queries are logically identical...

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) BETWEEN 1370521405 AND 1370732400;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2013-06-07 |
| 2013-06-08 |
| 2013-06-09 |
+------------+

SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE dt BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1370521405) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1370732400);
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2013-06-07 |
| 2013-06-08 |
| 2013-06-09 |
+------------+
```

...and MySQL is clever enough to utilise the (PK) index to resolve both queries (rather than reading the table itself - yuk).

But while the first requires a full scan over the entire index (good but not great), the second is able to access the table with a key over one (or more) value ranges (terrific)...

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) BETWEEN 1370521405 AND 1370732400;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL | 10957 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+

EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE dt BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1370521405) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1370732400);
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```